# ES6 import for 'ava' test not working

Tags: javascript, testing, ava

I followed the docs to create my first test using **ava** but it doesn't seem to run properly. I get the error below. I tried adding `import 'babel-register';` at the top of the file, and it works, but only if I run one specific test file. e.g. `ava ./test/helpers/test_helper.js`. Running `ava` on its own though... results in the import error below. Does anyone else know how to fix this? The getting started guide uses ES6 import and I have no idea why mine doesn't just work.

> (function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import
>   test from 'ava';
>                                                                 ^^^^^^ SyntaxError: Unexpected token import

**test.js**

```
import test from 'ava';

test(t => {
  t.deepEqual([1, 2], [1, 2]);
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add to your `package.json`

```
"ava": {
  "files": [
    "test/**/*.js"
  ],
  "require": [
    "babel-register"
  ],
  "babel": "inherit"
},
```

Your `.babelrc`

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015"]
}
```

And then your imports should work.

Comment: awesome! that fixed the error, but I get another problem. I'll post it above, would be great to hear your thoughts :)

Comment: Is this still relevant for AVA 1.x?

Answer (score 27):

there is a far easier way to work with ES module for AVA

```sh
$ npm install esm --save-dev
```

Then in your package.json add

```
{
    "ava": {
        "require": [
            "esm"
        ]
    }
}
```

Babel never works correctly, I spend more time on debugging the tool then my code with all this pile of CS everyday!

Comment: I found this to be the easiest and cleaner solution.

Comment: Holy smokes. I cannot believe this just worked. I've been wading through a babel upgrade on an old site that used AVA with so much pain and frustration. Im in disbelief that `esm` just nailed it on the first try.

Comment: No longer supported.

Comment: I saw the no longer supported comment, but it all worked for me just now -- what am I  missing?

Answer (score 1):

add this to your package.json

```
 "ava": {
    "babel": true
  }
```

e.g.

https://github.com/e2e-boilerplate/selenium-webdriver-es-modules-babel-ava/blob/master/package.json

https://github.com/e2e-boilerplate/puppeteer-es-modules-babel-ava/blob/master/package.json

Answer (score 0):

For me it was enough to just add

```json
"type": "module",
```

to my `package.json`

in order to make

```js
import test from 'ava';

test('foo', t => {
    t.pass();
});
```

run correctly.

Answer (score -2):

After you have yarm/npm installed it, did you run `ava --init`?

In package.json, what does the command say?
If you run (if you use npm) `npm run test`, it should execute the command in your package.json.

If you then have any .js (ES6) in your test directory, it should execute it (example is also on their github page https://github.com/avajs/ava).

You don't need to add all of that which is mentioned in the above comment.
These commands should get you a working run:

```
mkdir avatest
cd avatest
npm init
npm install --global ava (you probably did this already)
npm install --save-dev ava
ava --init
touch test/test.js
atom test/test.js (pasted your script)
npm run test
> 1 passed
```

Comment: Downvoted because this answer addresses setting up AVA but the question asked is about the error that occurs when a file you're importing into the test file uses "import" or "export" or whatever feature that needs to be transpiled. AVA mentions that it doesn't transpile code that in imported into a test but does show how you might get it working: https://github.com/avajs/ava#transpiling-imported-modules

Comment: Alternatively, it could be downvoted because it does not work. First, the list of instructions doesn't mention that you need to set "test": "ava" inside the "script" key in your package.json. After that, I get the error message "TypeError: Tests must have a title". This is likely due to me using a newer version of ava: 2.4.0. A horrible change if you ask me since the output gives you the line number, so there's no need to name each test.